# How to add a plugin to nopcommerce2.65 for makin free shipping to Russia

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, nopcommerce, razor-2

This is the shipping rules i need to implement:
1. Pick up in Moscow office.
2. Moscow Delivery - Free
3. Russian Post office - $10
4. EMS or SPSR - $20... where do i start? im a total frsher in asp.net MVC and razor